# Is there a way to read a volatile value from an unaligned address on stable Rust?

Tags: rust, memory-alignment, unsafe

I want to fetch ACPI's XSDT. Getting the table needs volatile access. Also, the header or the entries may not be well-aligned because the header size is 36 bytes, while the required alignment is 8 bytes. So, I want a function that reads a volatile value from an unaligned address. [`read_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html) requires a well-aligned address. Rust also provides [`unaligned_volatile_load`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.unaligned_volatile_load.html), but I don't want to use any nightly features because their behaviors frequently change. Is there a way to do this on stable Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the header is only 36 bytes, you can use `std::ptr::read_volatile` to copy it with minimal overhead into a `[u8; 36]`. From there you can use [`std::ptr::read_unaligned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_unaligned.html) which does not require nightly.

If you are mostly concerned with a nightly build changing you could also choose a specific nightly build and stick to that so it is at least consistent, e.g.:

```
rustup install nightly-2021-08-09
```

Comment: Or you could create an `union` with this `[u8; 36]` and a carefully designed, `repr(C)` struct, then `read_volatile` into the first, and read normally from the second.

Comment: @rodrigo that's actually a nice approach for readability. You would need to use `packed` too though.

Comment: Looking at the definition of the [ACPI headers](https://wiki.osdev.org/XSDT), it looks like there are designed to not need padding, so the `packed` should make no difference.